# hooking into UIPopoverDelegate method for resizing the popover: contentSizeForViewInPopover

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipopovercontroller

I am looking to implement the same behavior of the nice smooth expansion of the frame in a `UIPopoverController` when you changes it's `UIView`'s size but using the [WEPopoverController](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover).  Currently it is not implemented.

Is there something fired when the property `contentSizeForViewInPopover` changes in a `UIPopoverController` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line in your class.

```
[aView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:0 context:NULL];
```

And implement the following method. It will get called every time the frame of the view gets changed.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"frame"]) {
//Your code here
}
}
```

Don't forget to remove the observer when you are not in need of it.

```
[aView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame"];
```